# Python 3.3 Code to Download a file to a location and save as a given file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, download

For example I would like to save the .pdf file @ http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07825 with the filename: 'Data Assimilation- A Mathematical Introduction' at the location 'D://arXiv'.

But I have many such files. So, my input is of the form of a .csv file with rows given by (semi-colon is the delimiter):

```
url; file name; location.
```

I found some code here: https://github.com/ravisvi/IDM

But that is a bit advanced for me to parse. I want to start with something simpler. The above seems to have more functionality than I need right now - threading, pausing etc.

So can you please write me a very minimal code to do the above:

1. save the file 'Data Assimilation- A Mathematical Introduction'
2. from 'http://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.07825'
3. at 'D://arXiv'?

I think I will be able to generalize it to deal with a .csv file.

Or, hint me a place to get started. (The github repository already has a solution, and it is too perfect! I want something simpler.) My guess is, with Python, a task as above should be possible with no more than 10 lines of code. So tell me important ingredients of the code, and perhaps I can figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: I think if you ask a more specific question, you'll get more useful replies. What you need is to parse a csv file (take a look at [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)) and download a file and save it (see [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) and others). I suggest you try to implement something using these functions and ask a question if you have a specific problem that you cannot find a solution for.

Comment: I know how to parse .csv file. I need code for downloading at a location/renaming. I am editing the question. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: In reply to your edit: it is great that you are working on the question to state your needs accurately; however, "please give me an example so I don't have to read the docs" questions are not considered on-topic (or at least good) on this site. As the [ask] guide says, you are supposed to research your problem, and that certainly implies reading the docs.

Comment: Thanks for the continuous feedback! I read the [urllib.request.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) page, but it didn't answer my question. Please point me to somewhere else, if you have anything in mind. Thanks again for the comments!

Comment: Give me a hints on where to get started at least! I know I have to use the OS library for renaming.  I have used urllib for fetching htmls. But I have never downloaded anything. Tell me which library to use. I am willing to try and fail and come back to tell! Or may be I will succeed.. :)

Comment: Edited question again.

Comment: This is one case where I strongly feel like asking "does it *have* to be in python? Doesn't Windows have a version of wget or something?"

Comment: Sure! But the rest of my code is already in python: 1. I am getting the urls by crawling, 2. The file names by title of the page . So I want the rest of it to be in python as well. But if you have alternative ideas - sure I am game! Thanks!

Comment: I did hint you a place to get started in my first comment, where I linked to a function that does exactly what you are asking. If you have a specific problem using it, you can ask a question about it (or heavily edit this question).

Comment: I am sorry - I started looking right from the top of the page. I think I see how to do it - let me try. If it works, I will post the code here! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `requests` module, you can just `pip install requests`.
Then, the code is simple:

```
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
if response.ok:
    file = open(file_path, "wb+") # write, binary, allow creation
    file.write(response.content)
    file.close()
else:
    print("Failed to get the file")
```

Comment: I think I installed requests - but I still get the message: No module named 'requests'.

I am on windows and this is what I did: 1. open cmd.exe 2. change directory to C:/python33 3. Run: python get-pip.py 4. I got a message saying installation was successful. 5. Change directory to C:/python33/scripts. 6. Run: pip install requests. 6. I didn't get any message but it existed to the command prompt as usual. 7. I went back to C:/python33. 8. inside python I tried import requests and I got that error message. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you installed it for the right version of python? maybe try pip3, if you are using python 3. I am not on windows, so I am not sure how it works there with pip.

Comment: Alright I fixed it. (The correct way is to use python -m pip install requests).

But I got this error: 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/New Folder' at file = open('C:/New Folder', "wb+")

Comment: You need to give it the full file path, not just the folder, also make sure you can write in that directory - best use a relative path

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3.6.5

Here is a method that can create a folder and save the file in a folder. 
dataURL - Complete URL path 
data_path - Where the file needs to be saved. 
tgz_path - Name of the datafile with the extension.

```
def fetch_data_from_tar(data_url,data_path,tgz_path):
if not os.path.isdir(data_path):
    os.mkdir(data_path)
    print ("Data Folder Created @ Path", data_path)
else: 
    print("Folder path already exists")
tgz_path = os.path.join(data_path,tgz_path)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(data_url,filename=tgz_path)
data_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
data_tgz.extractall(path=data_path)
data_tgz.close()
```